# how to rewrite url with hash # using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect `http://terrychew.com.sg/classes` to `http://terrychew.com.sg/math-olympiad-singapore#Primary` because without the `#Primary`, the tab I want users to see will not be selected.

.htaccess converts my `#` into `%23` which doesn't work for me. I read on another thread that this code can be used to redirect with hashtags in the url

```
if (window.location.hash == "#/de/about/blog/") {
    window.location = 'http://google.com.ua';
    }
```

however, in this case, the OLD url contains the hashtag. I need code that works when the NEW url contains the hashtag. I tried reversing the code but it does not work

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^terrychew\.com\.sg$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.terrychew\.com\.sg$
RewriteRule ^classes\.html$ "http\:\/\/terrychew\.com\.sg\/math\-olympiad\-singapore" [R=301,L]

Comment: this code was generated in .htaccess by my server. i used cPanel to perform a 301 redirect. However, if I add a # in the NEW url, it appears as %23 in my browser which is useless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not using the [`NE`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags#flag_ne) flag.

> By default, special characters, such as `&` and `?`, for example, will
>   be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [`[NE]` flag](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/rewrite/flags#flag_ne)
>   prevents that from happening.